# Update Excel sheet from content of a ftp folder with date and time

Tags: excel, vba, ftp

I have a folder on a shared network. I want that whenever that folder is updated e.g. if 10 pdf files are placed in that folder, the column in the Excel sheet gets updated on a single click and shows a count 10 in a column and time of last update file in other folder.

Above is just a scenario, I have to implement this for very big data with multiple files & folders and lastly I'm going to implement it on Google doc spreadsheet.

Answer (score 0):

You would need to access the contents of a folder directory `Dir()`, you can then specify a network drive for example: `\\SERVER\Folder\`

Below is an example to get you started:

```
Sub GetDirectoryContents()

Dim row As Integer, Folder As String, Directory As String
Directory = "\\Your Folder\"
row = 1
Cells(row, 1) = "FileName"
Cells(row, 2) = "Size"
Cells(row, 3) = "Date/Time"


'Get Directory
Folder = Dir(Directory)

Do While Folder <> ""

row = row + 1

Cells(row, 1) = Folder

Cells(row, 2) = FileLen(Directory & Folder)

Cells(row, 3) = FileDateTime(Directory & Folder)

'Get next File
Folder = Dir()
Loop

End Sub
```

If you want to update this information when the workbook opens you can call this code on within the `ThisWorkbook` module:

```
Private Sub Workbook_Open()
GetDirectoryContents()
End Sub
```